# Preferences Error on IMac Yosemite 10.10.2

Tags: macos, error, preferences

Preferences app launches fine and all but one prefs pane work well -- the Desktop & Screen Saver preference pane yields the following message:

*"Preferences Error.  Could not load Desktop & Screen Saver preference pane."*

I have tried deleting the  com.apple.systempreferences.plist file and re-starting.  I have also restored this file from a Time Machine backup.  And I repaired permissions. Nothing helped.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: What is it in your Desktop + Screen Saver that it does not likes?

Comment: Good question, Buscar!  Wish I knew.

Comment: do you have any custom stuff in screen saver? do you have any custom desktops ? Turn desktop in to solid colors.

Comment: Try creating a new user and see if you get the issue there.

Comment: Buscar, no custom stuff other than wallpaper, which seems to be fine.  Can't change desktop to solid color because can't get to Pref Pane.

Comment: Kevin, guest user *IS* able to get to Pref Pane without any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Solved.

Deleted the file desktoppicture.db  located in user/library/applicationsupport/dock.  Then re-started.  This restored the default wallpaper.

Even though my previous wallpaper displayed without issue, it apparently caused a problem for the Desktop & Screen Saver Prefs.  I checked the jpg and it wasn't corrupt.

If I pick another image for my wallpaper the Prefs error returns, but at least for now everything is stable!

Many thanks to Kevin G. and Buscar for the suggestions.